# Scaling mouse drawings elements on a html canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas

Is there any way to scale drawing elements on a canvas? I'm creating an application where then user can place points on a canvas, but when I try to resize the browser window all the elements disappear.

My initial tentative was to calculate the screen difference before and after the resizing. After I get the percentages, I just sat the scale on the canvas and place the coordinates that was saved from the first time I drew on the canvas, but still doesn't work, if the points appear on the canvas, it is on the same place without scaling. Can someone give me little line of thought?

```
private calculateCanvasScreenDifference(previousSize, guestScreen) {

    return ((controlScreen - currentSize) * 100) / controlScreen;
}

let difWidthPercent = Math.abs(this.calculateCanvasScreenDifference(canvasPreviousWidth, canvasWidth) * 0.01);
let difHeightPercent = Math.abs(this.calculateCanvasScreenDifference(canvasPreviousHeight, canvasHeight) * 0.01);                        

let scaleX = ((Math.abs(difWidthPercent) <= 1) ? 1.00 - difWidthPercent : difWidthPercent - 1.00);
let scaleY = ((Math.abs(difHeightPercent) <= 1) ? 1.00 - difHeightPercent : difHeightPercent - 1.00);

this.cx.scale(Number(scaleX), Number(scaleY));

...
...

// then start recreating the drawing that was previous saved on an array of object(x, y values)

this.cx.beginPath();
this.cx.arc(coord.x, coord.y, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
this.cx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of your canvas width and start with a scale factor of 1.

```
let originalWidth = canvas.width;

let scale = 1;
```

On resize calculate the new scale factor. And update tracked canvas size.

```
let scale = newWidth / originalWidth;
originalWidth = newWidth;
```

Use the scale factor for all drawing at all times. e.g.

```
context.arc(coord.x * scale, coord.y * scale, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
```

**Note:** This approach assumes the original and new canvas sizes are proportional. If not then you will need to track width and height, and calculate separate x and y scale factors.